# Building gencpp from source

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build gencpp from source on a Fedora 18 system. I think I have the prerequisites already built: catkin and genmsg; however, during the build, cmake fails to find the genmsg cmake files. Here's the error:

```
+ /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr -DINCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR:PATH=/usr/include -DLIB_INSTALL_DIR:PATH=/usr/lib64 -DSYSCONF_INSTALL_DIR:PATH=/etc -DSHARE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/share -DLIB_SUFFIX=64 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /builddir/build/BUILD/gencpp-0.4.12/build/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3") 
-- Found PY_em: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/em.pyc  
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /builddir/build/BUILD/gencpp-0.4.12/build/test_results
-- catkin 0.5.64
CMake Error at /usr/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "genmsg" with any
  of the following names:
    genmsgConfig.cmake
    genmsg-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "genmsg" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "genmsg_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "genmsg"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.tRuPTe (%build)
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.tRuPTe (%build)
```

I've tried to define the genmsg_DIR variable as suggested in the error too, but it doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
+ /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr -DINCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR:PATH=/usr/include -DLIB_INSTALL_DIR:PATH=/usr/lib64 -DSYSCONF_INSTALL_DIR:PATH=/etc -DSHARE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/share -DLIB_SUFFIX=64 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON .. -Dgenmsg_DIR=/builddir/build/BUILDROOT/ros-gencpp-groovy-0.4.12-1.fc18.x86_64//usr/share/genmsg/cmake
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /builddir/build/BUILD/gencpp-0.4.12/build/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3") 
-- Found PY_em: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/em.pyc  
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /builddir/build/BUILD/gencpp-0.4.12/build/test_results
-- catkin 0.5.64
CMake Error at /usr/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "genmsg" with any
  of the following names:
    genmsgConfig.cmake
    genmsg-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "genmsg" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
```

The ros-genmsg-groovy package that I built does have the genmsgConfig.cmake file:

```
[ankur@dhcppc1  ros-repo]$ rpm -qpl ros-genmsg-groovy-0.4.18-1.fc18.noarch.rpm | egrep cmake
/usr/share/genmsg/cmake
/usr/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake
/usr/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsgConfig-version.cmake
/usr/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsgConfig.cmake
/usr/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-genmsg.cmake.em
/usr/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-genmsg.context.in
/usr/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-msg-paths.cmake.in
[ankur@dhcppc1  ros-repo]$
```

EDIT:

Attempts with the -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH addition as suggested:

```
+ /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr -DINCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR:PATH=/usr/include -DLIB_INSTALL_DIR:PATH=/usr/lib64 -DSYSCONF_INSTALL_DIR:PATH=/etc -DSHARE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/share -DLIB_SUFFIX=64 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/builddir/build/BUILDROOT/ros-gencpp-groovy-0.4.12-1.fc18.x86_64//usr/share/genmsg/cmake
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /builddir/build/BUILD/gencpp-0.4.12/build/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /builddir/build/BUILDROOT/ros-gencpp-groovy-0.4.12-1.fc18.x86_64//usr/share/genmsg/cmake
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3") 
-- Found PY_em: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/em.pyc  
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /builddir/build/BUILD/gencpp-0.4.12/build/test_results
-- catkin 0.5.64
CMake Error at /usr/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "genmsg" with any
  of the following names:
    genmsgConfig.cmake
    genmsg-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "genmsg" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "genmsg_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "genmsg"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.TVQb8z (%build)
RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.TVQb8z (%build)
Child return code was: 1
EXCEPTION: Command failed. See logs for output.
```

The contents of the genmsg rpm are [here](http://ankursinha.fedorapeople.org/genmsg-filelist.txt): That's all the files it generated. I may have moved them around a little to follow the FHS though.

I'm using the standard Fedora build system, building a tool called "[mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Using_Mock_to_test_package_builds)" which is really just a build tool. It creates a chroot and installs the build dependencies etc. It follows the normal rpm building workflow. I've placed the "spec files" [here](http://ankursinha.fedorapeople.org/ros-groovy/SPECS/).

I need to build the build dependencies for each package before I can attempt to build it, so a sequential order is to be followed.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58355/building-gencpp-from-source/) by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-03-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you need to add the installation prefix of `genmsg` to your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. In your case I think this might be:

`-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/builddir/build/BUILDROOT/ros-gencpp-groovy-0.4.12-1.fc18.x86_64//usr/`

But without knowing more about your build environment I don't think I will be able to give you the exact solution.

Also, did you ensure that the `genmsg-config.cmake` was in the the path you get for `genmsg_DIR`?

EDIT:

You should look for `genmsg-config.cmake` OR `genmsgConfig.cmake`

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) on 2013-03-18**:
I've updated the question with more information, on the build system, and attempts with the -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. The genmsg package did not generate a genmsg-config.cmake file though.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-18**:
It should generate a genmsgConfig.cmake file, I was thinking it was the other one, but in fact its the first.

**Comment by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) on 2013-03-18**:
The file is available at: /usr/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsgConfig.cmake. For the buildroot, it would become /builddir/build/BUILDROOT/ros-gencpp-groovy-0.4.12-1.fc18.x86_64//usr/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsgConfig.cmake.  Maybe I need to place the cmake file in another location, where cmake can find it.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-06-22**:
CMake finds config files in various locations http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:find_package

catkin uses `PREFIX/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsgConfig.cmake`. Make sure `PREFIX` is part of the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and the file exists. Also remove previous `CMakeCache.txt` files.